# Creating new command line interface for OS X application

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, command-line, applescript

I want to create a new command for my OS x app.

For example, calling this command in terminal/applescript:

oascript -s 'tell application "[MYAPP]" to [FUNCTION] with parameters [PARAMETER1,2,etc.]'

I'm pretty sure I'm using incorrect vocab to describe this as my search attempts have been unsuccessful.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to explicitly support scripting of your app. Check out the [Apple Developer guide on this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptX/Concepts/scriptable_apps.html).